# adb backup - no prompt on phone

Tags: android, cmd, sdk, adb, backup

I'm trying to use adb backup with:

```
adb backup "-apk -shared -all -f C:\Users\user\backup.ab"
```

on my elephone u3h.

Phone is configurated with programmer options and it is seen in:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
ELEExxxxx        device
```

After backup command I can see:

```
WARNING: adb backup is deprecated and may be removed in a future
release Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation...
```

Problem is that there is no prompt on phone that I should confirm backup and
in windows cmd command is stopped,
Did anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here's what Always worked for me: put single quotes around the parameters.

> for example :

```
adb backup '-all -apk -shared -f momsmobile.ab'
```

> Also , is Your  "USB Debugging(Security Settings)" - is ON or OFF ? If its off , then turn On because Modern Phones has more than one Option of USB Debugging

Comment: Great! Thank you. Those single quotes helped.

Comment: turns out "Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation" without any prompt on the phone happens whenever the options are invalid. I typed `--all` instead of `-all`, but no error message, just that line and back to the shell prompt.